# How to say "go wrong?"

Tags: words, syntax

If one wanted to say "go wrong" like in the sentence "anything that could go wrong will go wrong", how do they say it.

Comment: Is it Murphy's law?

Comment: For what it's worth: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E6%B3%95%E5%89%87

Comment: Wikipedia says "失敗する" and "うまく行かなくなる".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I would use 想定外 "soutei-gai"　(unexpected) as something that "goes wrong" is an in essence unexpected. Then as for the sentence

maybe something like this would work... I just kinda made it up on the fly.

想定外になれるものではあれば、想定外になる

Comment: I'm afraid to say this but 想定外になれるものではあれば、想定外になる doesn't make much sense...

Answer (score 3):

"Anything that could go wrong will go wrong" can be translated as:

- **うまく行かない**可能性があるものは、**うまく行かない** (lit. "not to go well")
- **失敗する**かもしれないものは、**失敗する** (lit. "to fail")